# Dynamically adding hyperlinks to selected text in RichTextBox text c#

Tags: c#, .net, richtextbox

i want to add hyperlink to specific text which is selected. i am using richtextbox for sending formatted text in email but i a unable to add hyperlink to a specific text.
like my richtextbox contains text "For more information click here" i want to add hyperlink to click here dynamically. Thanks in advance

Comment: this has been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279061/dynamically-adding-hyperlinks-to-a-richtextbox

Answer (score -2):

You can dynamically replace **"click here"** with

`<a href="your link">click here</a>`

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This is about RTF, not HTML.

Comment: @JohnWillemse: he is sending the text in email. So, if he replaces the text dynamically before putting in mail body, and sets `IsHtmlEnabled = true` , he can achieve what he wants.

Comment: @Avishek True. After re-reading the question it's a bit ambigeous indeed what exactly is the requirement.